# Why does anime.js not animate the left property in Firefox or Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, microsoft-edge, anime.js

I am trying to dynamically animate a styled div relative to some other divs, the number and position of which are only known at run-time.

The following SSCCE runs perfectly in Chrome but not at all in either Firefox or Edge. Does anyone know why?

I've looked at a number of other similar questions with no luck and to say the anime.js documentation is minimal is being polite.

```js
import anime from "./anime.es.js";

var pips = document.getElementsByClassName("pip");
var fill = document.querySelector(".pip-fill");

var pipBorder = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(pips[0]).borderWidth);

fill.style.left = (pips[0].offsetLeft + pipBorder) + "px";
fill.style.top = (pips[0].offsetTop + pipBorder) + "px";

anime({
    targets: fill,
    left: (pips[2].offsetLeft + pipBorder) + "px",
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 1000
});
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.pip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 64px;
    background-color: red;
}

.pip-fill {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pip"></div>
        <div class="pip"></div>
        <div class="pip"></div>
        <div class="pip-fill"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd one but might help someone else. I am offsetting the position of the filled div by the border width of the target divs. For some reason in both Firefox and Edge the `window.getComputedStyle(pips[0]).borderWidth` is returning `NaN` but `window.getComputedStyle(pips[0]).borderTopWidth` is returning the correct value. I think this is probably a bug because `border-width` is set explicitly in CSS.

Comment: have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to debug the code, whether it displays some error? Besides, you could also check html element and the CSS style, whether it set this style or not.